# What’s the equivalent XPath for a CSS selector containing a class, child and adjacent sibling selector?

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors

I've got this:

```
li.current+li>a
```

However I have only a basic knowledge of XPath.
I need it for the AutoPager Firefox extension.

I'd also like to get the first match only.

Comment: http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html

Comment: I looked at that already, but how do you get the next sibling?

Comment: What about getting the first match?

Comment: I have //[li[@class='current']/following-sibling::li[1]/a

Answer (score 3):

If your `li` belongs to many classes, then...

```
//li[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' current ')]/following-sibling::*[1]/self::li/a
```

here's the same thing broken up over many lines for clarity:

```
//li[contains(
        concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),
        ' current '
     )
]/following-sibling::*[1]/self::li/a
```

citation: http://pivotallabs.com/users/alex/blog/articles/427-xpath-css-class-matching

I tested it with the [Online XPath 2 evaluator](http://www.xmltools.dk/) using the following XML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Consume usage app support thread #2 - Apps - iPhone - Whirlpool Forums
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <ul id="top_pagination" class="pagination ">
                <li class="first">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353">
                        first: 5 months ago
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353">
                        1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=2">
                        2
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=3">
                        3
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=4">
                        4
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=5">
                        5
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=6">
                        6
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=7">
                        7
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=8">
                        8
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=9">
                        9
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=10">
                        10
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=11">
                        11
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=12">
                        12
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=13">
                        13
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=14">
                        14
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=15">
                        15
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=16">
                        16
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=17">
                        17
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=18">
                        18
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=19">
                        19
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=20">
                        20
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=21">
                        21
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=22">
                        22
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=23">
                        23
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=24">
                        24
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=25">
                        25
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="current ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=26">
                        26
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=27">
                        27
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="last">
                    <a href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&amp;p=-1&amp;#bottom">
                        last: 2 hours ago
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should note that the page you linked to as your input - http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&p=26 - is HTML, not XML:

- its doctype declaration is for HTML 4.01
- the document contains unclosed tags like `<br>` which would have to be `<br />`

... so you may have problems using it as input for XPath evaluation.

Comment: @Alejandro - the formatting/highlighting makes the XPAth look weird; the first line looks like a comment... I'm going to put both one-line and multi-line formats.

Comment: I think that scrolling is worst for readability. Also, we take whitespace handling as a feature of XPath...

Comment: @Alejandro - Agreed; really I just don't like how the SO syntax highlighting treats the multi-line XPath... I wonder if there's a way to force the syntax highlighting to use a particular ruleset?

Comment: That's [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). It hasn't XPath support up today.

Answer (score 0):

`li.current + li > a` maps to:

```
//li[@class='current']/following-sibling::*[1]/self::li/a
```

If you want to select the first `a` child element, your CSS selector should be:

```
li.current + li > a:first-child
```

which maps to:

```
//li[@class='current']/following-sibling::*[1]/self::li/a[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still matches 2 instead of the first.

Comment: Take this page: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1543353&p=26 I'm using it for HTML.

Comment: I does work, and the space is ignored anyway classes are separated by spaces. But I'd like the XPath to only select the first match.

Comment: Do you mean only the first `a` child element? Because you'd need to change your CSS selector as well.

Comment: No just the first match of the whole XPath query.

Comment: The first match of the whole XPath query is the first `a` child element. Does adding `[1]` at the end of the expression work for you?